# HADOOP NAMENODE ERROR

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

I have successfully installed Hadoop in my ubuntu system.
But when i run the command ***start-all.sh*** all the daemons start except the namenode.
Please help me.[I Have attached the image with the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHOjq.png)

Comment: You could look in the log file for the namenode - the path is right there in your image.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Name Node Format Format it might work for You:

```
bin/hadoop namenode -format
```

and then try

```
start-all.sh
```